# How to test AG Grid with @testing-library/react?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, ag-grid-react

To test the `AgGridReact` component, one must wait for the `gridReady` event as suggested here:

https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/react/testing/

The suggested method seems to use enzyme (?) to call `mount` and inspect the component's `api` property for truthiness.

However, in `@testing-library/react`, it's not clear that inspecting the internal state of a component is possible; it is certainly discouraged, as discussed here:

https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/migrate-from-enzyme#why-should-i-use-the-react-testing-library

Because tests seem to require access to the internal state of AG Grid to know when to run a test, and `@testing-library/react` seems to disallow that access ... is there a way to test components that use AG Grid using `@testing-library/react`?